# Python: chardet.detect with a big binary object

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, binary, chardet

I get a some big files from a web page. They're binary. I need to scan them to detect thier encode, because chardet.detect let be my script too slow. I tought to use readline but i can't 'cause i have only binary. It's possibile to do something like readline on a binary  object?

Answer (score 1):

You can't know when there is a newline because you don't know how is it encoded. You can simply take a small part of your binary data `data[:100]` and run `chardet.detect` on that.

Comment: Thanks you! I'll try as soon as possibile!. So binary objects are something like array to select a part, cool